# Need help creating a relevancy calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

folks,

I admit that I'm not super strong with JS when it comes to math, so I'm reaching out here for some help. What I need to do is come up with a relevancy calculator that does the following:

Users have two number fields, the first is labeled '# of people', and the second is labeled '# irrelevant stories'. When the user enters a value for each field, the output on submit is calculated with the following: (# of people value x 0.20$) x (# irrelevant stories value x 30 seconds).

Any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't look too hard. Can you post your attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pretty simple solution:

Just get the values from the input fields and store them in respective variables.  Here's a JS function using those variables:

```
function calculation(people, stories) {
  return (people * 0.2 /* $ */) * (stories * 30 /* seconds */);
}
```

Then call your function and store the result, eg: `var result = calculation(4, 26);`

**Latest Edit**

Ok, given your latest JSFiddle, here's all you need in your html:  (remove everything else)

```
<body>
  <script>
    // calculate the fields
    var calculation = function() {
      var people = document.getElementById('people').value;
      var stories = document.getElementById('stories').value;
      var result = Math.floor(people * 0.2 * stories * 30);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
      return false;
    }
  </script>
  <form name="calculateIt">
    <input type="text" name="people" id="people">
    <input type="text" name="stories" id="stories">
    <input type="button" name="calculateIt" value="Calculate" onclick="calculation();">
  </form>        
  <span id="result"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Here's what I have, which includes what you shared above but it's not outputting for me. https://jsfiddle.net/L8b5rho3/

Comment: I've added an update to my answer to solve this.

Comment: Cool, thanks! i think I'm close. Here's an updated fiddle. The output's not generating on submit, though. https://jsfiddle.net/L8b5rho3/3/

Comment: Updated my answer further, this seems to work perfectly...

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks so much! One last question, which I've never tried before...how do I get the result to round to the nearest decimal point? For example, if a result is 3888.0000001, rounding that to 3888. Cheers!

Comment: Use the Math.floor() function.  I'll update my answer to include that too.
PS: Please accept my answer...

Comment: Done! Thanks once again, sir!

Comment: Glad I could help :)